# reduce opacity of "PNG" images in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, png

I want to reduce opacity of "PNG" images in IE. Alpha filter works well in mozilla but in IE there is black outline around image.

I dont want transparent PNG image for IE. I want to set opacity of PNG image in IE.

Thanks alot for help

Regards

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Answer (score 2):

In IE9, replace the Alpha filter with native CSS3 opacity. Downlevel, it's not really possible due to the "outline" problem you mention.

Comment: hi thanks for replying.....Ya you're right....so there is no way to overcome this....???!!!!

Comment: Upgrade to a later client, or pregenerate the merged image on the server (yuck).

Answer (score -1):

> Firefox uses the property opacity:x
>   for transparency, while IE uses
>   filter:alpha(opacity=x).

http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp

Comment: hi thanks for replying. Ya i know that. i tried using both but for PNG images, i dont get output in IE. everything works fine in firefox though.

Comment: Oh, PNG.The answer lies in here: